# get closest element with matching class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jquery 1.3.2. I would like to get closest div to clicked button, based on part of it's class name which begins allways with "wrapID-". Basicaly I have 2 submit forms on a page with same ID. There is a product image near each submit form. I need to print the image based on what button was clicked. My code does not work, what can be wrong? I do not have access to html, I am aware that same ids are not valid.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('.form-submit').click(function() {
var closestwrap = $(this).closest('div[class^="wrapID-"]');
cls = closestwrap.attr('class');
$('.'cls+' img').printElement();
}                           
});
```

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/gPJrB/3/

Comment: Can you post an actual example?  The one you posted is rife with syntax errors and `printElement` is not a function...

Comment: "I am using jquery 1.3.2" --- Why??? Upgrade!

Comment: @JanDvorak It is for drupal 6 which supports only this version

Comment: 1.5 is fully backwards compatible, 1.6-1.8 are backwards compatible to the same extent and they contain compatibility fixes for older versions. Please try swapping in 1.8 for 1.3 without Drupal noticing. I'm pretty sure nothing will break. Anyways, Drupal 6 itself is not exactly new. Can you upgrade Drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no use in trying to build another selector. Not only will this in general not work (what if `closestwrap` had multiple classes?), it's also inefficient.

Simply use `find` on `closestwrap` to find your `img` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.form-submit').click(function() {
        var closestwrap = $(this).closest('div[class^="wrapID-"]');
        closestwrap.find('img').printElement();
    });                  
});
```

I assume `$.printElement` is [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/tree/master/jQuery.printElement)? It might help if you'd include a link in your question next time.

**EDIT:** I checked your fiddle and it appears that your HTML structure was a bit awkward. I moved the submit buttons inside the `wrapID-*` `div`s so `closest` actually finds the `div`. [Check out the fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/f9YHm/)

Note that this plugin breaks in jQuery 1.9 and higher, the highest compatible version is 1.8. This is because it uses the deprecated `$.browser` properties for browser sniffing which have been removed in 1.9. You can use the jQuery Migrate plugin ([as in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/f9YHm/1/)) or update the plugin yourself. Chances are that these browser tests need revision for the latest versions of these browsers.

Comment: Hi, I thought printElement is a regular function. Now I see it is not. Should I use html() instead? There is a link with code http://jsfiddle.net/gPJrB/3/

Comment: @user1031743 If you want to print that image, then that plugin will do that. Just make sure to download and include `jquery.printElement.min.js` on your page (after including jQuery itself) and you should be good to go with this snippet.

Comment: I do not want to use any additional plugin.  I used html instead but I can not see if it actualy shows the image or not, probably because it is printing it on the same place? http://jsfiddle.net/gPJrB/4/ Is it possible to put closestwrap.find('img') into variable and work with it?

Comment: @user1031743 Sure, just store it using `var imgToPrint = closestwrap.find('img');` and work with it as any other jQuery object: inspect it, pass it around, call some methods, log some information (`console.log(imgToPrint.html())`),... Also, what's wrong with using a plugin to provide a printing function?

Comment: Hi, I tried to use it in variable but can not get any result please see http://jsfiddle.net/gPJrB/5/

Comment: @user1031743 See my edit. `closest` will give you an empty jQuery object using your HTML markup. `closest` finds the closest ancestor of `this` matching the selector, but the clicked submit button is *outside* that `div`. Therefore, no matches are found. I moved the button *inside* the `div`s (which is more logical) so it has a `wrapID-*` ancestor.

Comment: Thank you for patience with me. I updated my jsfiddle please see http://jsfiddle.net/gPJrB/6/ . Now buttons are inside divs. For testing I try to get image url, but can without results.

Comment: @user1031743 Simple: `getAttribute` is a method of a DOM element, but you're trying to use it on a jQuery object. Use `.attr('src')` instead. Alternatively, unwrap the jQuery object first using `image[0]` to get the underlying DOM element.